# Excel evaluate standard diviation of filtered data based on a criterion

Tags: excel, excel-formula, standard-deviation, subtotal

I have a table in excel with multiple columns (called [Group][ID][Variable][Woehler][Error]).

I want to find the standard deviation of the "Error".

Calculating the standard deviation of the filtered data is easily done by the SUBTOTAL function.

But what if I only want the standard deviation of the filtered data (say we filter by "Group") for a given "Woehler" of e.g. 3 (Woehler contains integer values from 3 to 14). So basicall I try to combine SUBTOTAL and IF. How can that be done?

I tried do to it in line with the

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109;INDIRECT(.....)*(....=3))
```

method which gave the total sum of the filtered data based on the condition stated after the "*". This worked for me but when I changed the 109 (which gives the filtered sum) to the code for filtered standard deviation, it would not give a result.

Comment: the 109 needs to stay to return the number.  The SUMPRODUCT is doing the SUM.  Try: `=STDEV.P(IF(SUBTOTAL(3;INDIRECT(.....))*(....=3);INDIRECT(.....)))` depending on version it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: Thank you. I now tried `=STDEV.P(IF(SUBTOTAL(109;INDIRECT("G"&ROW($S$2:$S$10000)))*($F$2:$F$10000=3);INDIRECT("G"&ROW($S$2:$S$10000))))`. I compared the result of the **unfiltered** data to another formula which always gives the unfiltered result and I did not get the same result at all. (formula for comparison is `=STDEV.P.S(IF(Table13[Woehler]=3;Table13[Error]))`). Any ideas on why that's the case?

Thank you for your help!:)